# Can I look up the query id from a SnowSql session in the Snowflake Interface?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to do the same thing using the SnowSql command line interface (CLI)? I'd like to view the SQL code for a particular query, as specified by its query ID, using the CLI.

When using the web console, one may go on the History tab and filter by "Query ID" e.g. "xxx-xxxxx" to view the SQL code and error messages (if any) for that particular query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [LAST_QUERY_ID](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html#last-query-id) to retrieve the query IDs for queries in your session.

`select last_query_id();` Gets the most Recent Query ID

`select last_query_id(1);` Gets the first Query ID of the session

`select last_query_id(-2);` Gets the Query ID from two queries ago.

etc.

Then you can use a query like this to get your actual Query Text if you need it.

```
SELECT QUERY_TEXT
  FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION(RESULT_LIMIT => 10))
 WHERE QUERY_ID = '018cde0c-0077-09ee-0000-001812d26346'
;
```

If you need to retrieve query information outside of your Session, I believe you can use [ACCOUNT_USAGE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html#query-history-view) if that works for you.

```
SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY WHERE QUERY_ID = '018cde0c-0077-09ee-0000-001812d26346';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this using QUERY_HISTORY* Tables:

```
SELECT query_id, query_text,user_name,session_id,role_name,warehouse_name,
       execution_status,error_code,error_message,start_time,end_time
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY(DATEADD('HOURS',-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
ORDER BY start_time;
```

Reference : https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html